# GoShippo API doesn't return rates in Europe

Tags: javascript, shippo

My requests to Shippo API doesn't return any `rates for EU`. Just successfully managed to get rates for `USA` and `UK`. But **I need** to make delivery from **Czech Republic to other countries**.

In my GoShippo account I currently have **`these carriers`**:

```
    Parcelforce 
    USPS
    Deutsche Post
    UberRUSH
    DHL Express
```

So this request...

```
{
  "object_purpose": "PURCHASE",

  "address_from": {
    "object_purpose": "PURCHASE",
    "name": "Mr Hippo",
    "street1": "80 Duke of York Square",
    "city": "London",
    "zip": "SW3 4LY",
    "country": "GB",
    "phone": "+1 406-452-6041",
    "email": "mrhippo@goshippo.com"
  },

  "address_to": {
    "object_purpose": "PURCHASE",
    "name": "Mr Hippo",
    "street1": "1-2 Oxford St",
    "city": "Manchester",
    "zip": "M1 5AN",
    "country": "GB",
    "phone": "+1 406-452-6041",
    "email": "mrhippo@goshippo.com"
  },

  "parcel": {
    "length": "5",
    "width": "5",
    "height": "5",
    "distance_unit": "in",
    "weight": "5",
    "mass_unit": "lb"
  },
  "async": false
}
```

...gives me [this rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg0Kw.png)

Because it is UK. Also I successfully get rates if I use USA addresses.

But if I try addresses from France, Germany, Croatia, Hungary, Switzerland, Poland, Czech Republic, Ukraine, Sweden etc., I never get any rates. I have tried a lot of combinations of parcel weight/size, lb/kg, in/cm, also have tried one/multiple parcels in one shipment.

What should I do to get rates exactly for delivery **form Czech Republic to EU countries**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get rates from other countries in Europe you need to add your own carrier accounts (https://goshippo.com/docs/carrier-accounts) for carriers that ship from those countries.

The Shippo's built-in master accounts only ship from specific countries:

- USPS, DHL Express, UberRush: US
- Parcelforce: UK
- Deutsche Post: DE

Most of them do ship TO all countries worldwide, but they are restricted in terms of FROM where they ship.

So to get rates from the Czech Republic you need to add your own account with a carrier that ships from the Czech Republic to the EU.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added a DHL account and it works, but for some reason gives **huge** rates. Something like — for parcel with 30*60*50cm and 2kg weight it gives about 350 euro cost shipping from Cyprus to Cyprus (local delivery). Will try to add other carriers to see what they will give back.

Comment: Could be dimensional pricing (very large packages with rather light weight are rated based on their dimension, not weight). Let me know in case you need any further help with these rates.

Comment: Thnks!! One more question — we added a DHL Express account and it works as expected until I try to ship array of 2 and more parcels. If so, I get empty rates list. Can I fix it somehow?

Comment: Our team is working on multi-piece shipment support for DHL Express at the moment, and we expect it to launch in Q1. Is the lack of support for this feature a blocker for you at this point?

Comment: Not a blocker, but it could be a cool feature. We are developing e-commerce app and customers can wish to buy multiple items. As I understand, currently I should make a loop over all items in cart and make shipping for each one, am I right? So right now I can't quickly imagine what is the right way to show rates for my customer to choose one. Seems like I should display a bunch of options for each cart item. It looks much stranger if customer wish to but multiple similar items. Maybe I can summarize weight and dimensions? Anyway.. multiple parcels in one shipment could look cooler : )

Comment: Oh is it right only for DHL Express or for all carriers? I just can't check other carriers right now.

Comment: Multi-piece shipments (MPS) are currently supported for FedEx and UPS. Many other carriers don't support MPS. DHL does support it but our team hasn't finished the integration yet, but we will release it in Q1. For all carriers that don't support MPS you have to create individual shipments for each parcel.

Comment: Got it, Simon. Thank you for you help!